# 'length error in the tickerplant kdb+/q

Tags: kdb

When I start up the tick.q with sym.q and feed.q with files provided as follows:

```
q tick.q sym -p 5010
q feed.q
```

Github links: https://github.com/KxSystems/cookbook/tree/master/start/tick ,
https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick

The tickerplant process prints `'length` error on every update, which usually occurs when incorrect number of elements is passed: https://code.kx.com/wiki/Errors

I suspect that this happens when the feed process calls .u.upd

Any suggestions as to how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Entering `\e 1` into the command line will suspend execution and run the debugger allowing you to see what failed and query the variables which should help pinpoint what is causing the issues.

More about debugging here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/debug/

Comment: Mark, thanks a lot for you response. After following you recommendation,  the debugger prints:```q)'length
  [0]  /home/eliquinox/dev/cookbook/start/tick/tick.q:45: .u.upd:
 if[not -16=type first first x;a:"n"$a;x:$[0>type first x;a,x;(enlist(count first x)#a),x]];
 f:key flip value t;pub[t;$[0>type first x;enlist f!x;flip f!x]];if[l;l enlist (`upd;t;x);i+:1];}
```   PS That is not a vanilla tick.q set up. I am using a custom feed handler. Also note that if use `insert` to insert into the table, everything works and tickerplant updates the tables

Comment: Using .z.ex once in the debugger will give you the failed primitive and .z.ey will give you the failed argument list, so you can hopefully see what part of the function is causing you problems

Comment: Insert will expect your data to be a nested list of columns, while upsert will expect it to be a nested list of rows. More discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/personal-kdbplus/JxPLxlmIzJs

Comment: .z.ex: `!`     .z.ey: ``` time`sym`systemtime`side`amount`price
(0D21:48:03.178885000;2018.06.14T20:48:01.975;`XBTUSD;2018.06.14T20:48:03.178.. ```  I can see that timespan column got appended to the table. By the way the schema of this table is ```trade:([]time:`datetime$();sym:`symbol$();systemtime:`datetime$();side:`symbol$();amount:`int$();price:`float$()) ```

Comment: Reading through tick.q it seems that if the first value on the first row is not of timespan type it will append on "n"$.z.P as the first value.

You have many options here, you can either,
1) edit the table schemas to include the time column of type timespan.
2) put systemtime first but cast it to a timespan type so that a new time column isn't appended
3) since you already have a systemtime column of timestamps, a suggestion would be to put your systemtime as the first column and edit tick.q to check for timestamps (-12 = type x) as the first column instead of timespans

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the plain vanilla tick setup from KX there is no reason for that error to appear.

Also, I think you need to start the feed as `feed.q -t 200` otherwise you will get no data coming through.

Usually the `'length` error appears when the table schema does not match. So if you have the `sym.q` file (and it is loaded correctly) you should not have that issue.

Just to confirm this is the structure of your directory:

```
.
├── feed.q
├── README.md
├── tick
│   ├── r.q
│   ├── sym.q
│   └── u.q
└── tick.q
```

The `sym.q` file contains your table schema. If you change something in the feedhandler the table schema in the `sym.q` must match that change (i.e if you add a column in the feed you must also add a holder in the table for that column)

Comment: Alex, I may have magled with the "vanilla" set up when I was trying to set up a custom feedhandler, so my apologies for misrepresenting the problem. When I tested with the original tickerplant files again with code that I provided above, I no longer get the 'length error message, but I get no updates in the tickerplant either. And the directory structure matches the one you outline above.

Comment: start a q process and do the following:

1. ```h:hopen`:localhost:port:user:pass``` (leave user and pass empty if you don't have any)

2. define the ```upd:{[t;x] show x}```

3. ```h(`.u.sub;`;`)```

and see if you have anything printed on screen

Comment: After doing that, the terminal outputs the respective schemas of quotes and `trades:`quote +`time`sym`bid`ask`bsize`asize`mode`ex!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`fl..
`trade +`time`sym`price`size`stop`cond`ex!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`float$..`

Comment: you must have a `feed.q` process running now. can you please type `\t` and see what number it returns? if it `0` then type `\t 200i` where the number represents the frequency in milliseconds for pushing data to the tickerplant. once you do that you should see a lot of tables coming through the q process which is subscribing to the tickerplant.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new q session on some port (9999), add your schema definition there and define `insert` as `.u.upd` or something like this :

```
.u.upd:{[t;d]
 .test.t:t;
 .test.d:d;
 t upsert d
}
```

Now point your feed to this q session and stream some data; this will enable you to analyse the test variables in case of the errors.